# Accessing Local Files from Assets Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm trying to copy a local .pdf to a temporary location to be able view it using PDFSharp.

[image]

MainActivity:

```
            AssetManager assetManager = this.Assets;
          
            string filename = "test.pdf";
            string path = this.FilesDir + Java.IO.File.Separator;
            // returns /data/user/0/com.companyname.sample/files/

            try
            {
                File.Copy(Path.Combine(path, filename),
                    Path.Combine(systemHelper.GetTemporaryDirectory(), filename), true);



                // Open the file (systemHelper.GetTemporaryDirectory() returns = /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.app/files)
                PdfDocument inputDocument = PdfReader.Open(Path.Combine(systemHelper.GetTemporaryDirectory(), filename), PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);
               
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
```

Error : "Could not find file "/data/user/0/com.companyname.sample/files/test.pdf""

i would like to access the pdf file using `FileStream`

```
var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

Comment: xamarin.forms or xamarin.Android?

Comment: that's  for xamarin forms, but i'm focusing on android first

Comment: https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/pdf-viewer/getting-started

Comment: I'm trying for a open source solutions haha, but thanks for the input

Comment: license-free https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense

Comment: @RyanMotal Did you find a solution to this? I'm porting a Xamarin.Android app to Xamarin.Forms and would like to access the Assets folder too. But I can't find an easy way to do this.

Comment: unfortunately @Dominique , I did not find solution to this problem.

Comment: @Ryan Motal I found a solution and I've submitted a PR to the Xamarin.Essestials project. It's currently in review. Look for my branch dominique-CleanGetFilesAndDirectories. Once merged it should work across all supported platforms.

Comment: That's awesome @Dominique, I'll definitely check that out

Answer (score 3):

In Xamarin Android, if you want to read PDF in Asscts subfolder, you could use `AssetManager`.

```
   AssetManager assets = this.Assets;
        // Read the contents of our asset
        string content;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(assets.Open("Template/test.pdf")))
        {
            content = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

[image]

If you want to read in Xamarin.Forms, you could use Dependency Service.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction

Comment: Have you set the Build Action to `AndroidAsset`?

Comment: yes i did, i even ran it in MainActivity just to make sure

Comment: Wait for a monent. I would upload the source file on Github.

Comment: Thanks, one more thing, how can you get the exact path for the file, when using FileStream? just in case i want to edit the .pdf file

Comment: GitHub: https://github.com/WendyZang/Test/tree/master/App1 AssetManager provides access to an application's  asset files. For the subfolder, you could use `Template/test.pdf` to get.